# Authorizing commands via tacacs+ server executed in shell by ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, pam, aaa-security-protocol

I've setup a tacacs+ server and a PAM tacacs client from here- https://github.com/kravietz/pam_tacplus/tree/main.

When user ssh into the tacacs client machine, I want authentication from tacacs+ server and allow execution of only those commands in shell which are allowed in the tacacs+ server config.

Authentication works but I can't get shell commands authorisation to work.

What changes would I have to do for this to work.

This is the tacacs+ server config where I have allowed only ls command:

```
key = testkey123

user = testuser1 {
        cmd = ls {
                permit .*
        }
        global = cleartext "testpass123"
        service = ppp protocol = ip {
                addr=1.2.3.4
        }
}
```

I have also created a local user on the client with the same credential as in the server config.

This is the PAM test module that I defined at /etc/pam.d:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       sufficient /lib/security/pam_tacplus.so server=127.0.0.1 secret=testkey123
account    sufficient /lib/security/pam_tacplus.so server=127.0.0.1 secret=testkey123 service=ppp protocol=ip
session    sufficient /lib/security/pam_tacplus.so server=127.0.0.1 secret=testkey123 service=ppp protocol=ip
```

In the PAM sshd module present in /etc/pam.d I have added:

```
auth include test
account include test
session include test
```

In the tacacs+ config, I have allowed only "ls" command, but all commands can be executed. The client doesn't seem to authorise permitted commands from the server.